# SyntaxError: can't assign to function call (For Loop)

Tags: python, for-loop

Hi I am trying to create a new array from a previous array. such that in new array the first element is mean of first 20 elements from existing array. Here is my code. I am not sure why its not working.

```
#Averages
RPMA=[]
for i in range(9580):
  for j in range (0,191600):
    a=RPM.iloc[j:j+20]
    RPMA(i)= a.mean()
```

Comment: `RPMA(i)= a.mean()` => `RPMA.append(a.mean())`. By the way, note that `i` plays no role here -- you should check if the first `for` loop is needed and why

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like you're using the wrong kind of brackets. This line:

```
RPMA(i)= a.mean()
```

...should probably be this:

```
RPMA[i]= a.mean()
```

But I'm no Python expert. I guessing that it thinks `RPMA(i)` is a function because you use parentheses, in which case you would be trying to assign a value to a function call, like the error says.

However trying to assign a new value past the end of the array will result in an `IndexError` because the array element doesn't exist, and will need to be added. What you can do instead is this:

```
RPMA.append(a.mean())
```

...which will append the data to the end of the array (i.e. adding a new element).

Comment: This is correct, but this would result in an `IndexError` when you try assigning out of the range of the list (e.g., `xs=[]; xs[0] = 3.14` is always an error.  You need to use `RPMA.append(a.mean())` to append to the end of the list in this case.

Comment: @drjimbob Do you mind if I include that information in my answer? I forgot to consider that you might need to add an extra element to the end of the array, because in JS you don't.

Comment: Yeah, no need to ask; this is a collaborative site.  Almost wrote this as an answer but someone had this as a comment earlier.  Your method would work if the array was the right-size when it was defined with something like `RPMA=[None,]*9580`.

Comment: @drjimbob Coolio, thanks. It is a collaborative site, yes, but it could be considered plagiarism if I just copied your information into my answer without asking. Plus it's just polite, and I've seen people get pretty upset if you don't ask first sometimes :)

Comment: @Clonkex I second that. I've seen people get pretty angry because they suddenly deiced they wanted to write they're own answer, based off of a comment they made on your post. I really don't see anything wrong with erring on the side of caution and asking, first.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone. As suggested by most of you, I made below changes in code and now its working just fine!

```
RPMA=[]
for j in range (0,191600, 20):
    a=RPM.iloc[j:j+19]
    RPMA.append(a.mean())
```