# "Can't assign to function call" error in if statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a program that takes a passage then displays the word count, average length of the words and how many times each word occurs. However whilst trying to implement the part where it finds how many times each word occurs an error occurred: "can't assign to function call" I have looked at other question where this has been asked however I have not been able to fit it. The error occurs on the "word_amount(wordposition) += 1" line.

```
passage = "this is a test to test this program"
words = passage.split()
wordcount = len(words)
print(passage)
print("Number of words:",wordcount)
wordlength = list(map(len, words))
avwordlength = (sum(wordlength))/wordcount
print("Average word length:",avwordlength)
checked_words = []
word_amount = []
for x in range(wordcount):
        currentword = words(x)
        if currentword in checked_words:
                wordposition = checked_words.index(currentword)
                word_amount(wordposition) += 1
        else:
                checked_words.append(currentword)
                word_amount.append(1)
print(checked_words)
print(word_amount)
```

Comment: use square brackets

Comment: you are trying to pass the variable as an argument


change word_amount(wordposition) to word_amount[wordposition]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SyntaxError: can't assign to function call (For Loop)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45778114/syntaxerror-cant-assign-to-function-call-for-loop)

Comment: Definitely a duplicate.  Joe, you should read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.  The mcve for this question is something like `word_amount(wordposition) += 1`.  All the other code you posted is just noise.

Answer (score 0):

Round brackets is for functions, that is why the error tells you that it is trying to interpret word amount as a function. you need to use square brackets, also for the words list three lines above